# How to subtract numpy arrays dynamically

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a method that returns some numpy array like below one

```
def numpy_array():
  ......
  ......
  return true, test_1, test_2, test_3
```

I have another method that calculates the subtraction between `true` and `rest of the arrays` like the below one

```
def subtraction():
  true, test_1, test_2, test_3 = numpy_array()
  sub_1 = np.subtract(true, test_1)
  sub_2 = np.subtract(true, test_2)
  ......
  ......
  return sub_1, sub_2
```

The problem is, I could have a lot of arrays in the `def numpy_array()` method. I want to write the `def subtraction()` method in a dynamic way. So that I do not need to subtract arrays manually (`np.subtract(true, test_1)`, `np.subtract(true, test_2)`, and so on).

Could you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: you will run into issues anyway you do it if you are writing functions with no input values.  Better would be `new_arr = subtraction(arr1, arr2)`... but numpy has already written that function for you, `np.subtract`.  I don't see the value in the function you've written

Comment: I did not get your idea. Would you mind elaborate?

Comment: Have you considered turning your `test_N` arrays into a single 3 x X array? If so, numpy's broadcasting features could do the subtraction for all of them in one step.

Comment: What is `True-True` supposed to do?

Comment: @hpaulj nothing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy_array` or any python function with multiple arguments will return a tuple.
You can then iterate over the tuple to get the differences you want:

```py
def subtraction():
  matrices = numpy_array()
  # a tuple of some number of numpy arrays

  first = matrices[0]  
  # the first array, 'true' in question

  result = [first - matrices[i] for i in range(1,len(matrices))]
  # the difference between the first and subsequent arrays

  return tuple(result)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But what is the reason for using `tuple`?

Comment: Because otherwise it will return a list object,  created by the list comprehension.  A tuple is the default when returning multiple arguments in python but if you want a list there's no need for that bit.